For some finite group $G$ assume $X,Y \subset G, X \cap Y = \emptyset$. Compute subsets of $X$ and $Y$ that generate isomorphic subgroups of $G$.
For some finite group $G$ assume $X,Y \subset G, X \cap Y = \emptyset$. I need to compute subsets $X' \subset X$ and $Y' \subset Y$ that generate isomorphic subgroups of $G$: $\langle X' \rangle \leq G, \langle Y' \rangle \leq G, \langle X' \rangle \cong \langle Y' \rangle$.
Of course, the trivial example is cyclic groups of the same order. But I need these isomorphic subgroups to be big (generally, the bigger the better). $X$ and $Y$ don't have some special properties, for all we know they are just arbitrary subsets of $G$ that do not intersect, but it is known that $|X| = |Y|$.
Are there algorithms in computational group theory that address any similar problems?
As a sub-problem, I'm also wondering about the following: assume $X' \subset X, Y' \subset Y$ and we know that $\langle X' \rangle \cong \langle Y' \rangle$. For some elements $a,b \in G$ when are $\langle X' \cup \{a\} \rangle$ and $\langle Y' \cup \{b\} \rangle$ isomorphic? Initially I was thinking that if $ord(a) = ord(b)$ then these groups would be isomorphic which would have made things very easy, but apparently that's not so.

Certainly there is an algorithm: enumerate all subsets $X' \subset X$ and then, for each $X'$, enumerate the elements of $\left< X'\right>$; enumerate all subsets $Y' \subset Y$ and then, for each such $Y'$, enumerate the elements of $\left<Y'\right>$; now compare your list of the outcomes for $\left< X' \right>$ and your list of the outcomes for $\left< Y' \right>$ and look for matches.

@LeeMosher but how do you identify a match? the problem of deciding whether two groups are isomorphic is undecidable, isn't it?

The problem of deciding whether two finitely presented groups are isomorphic is undecidable. But the same problem for finite groups is certainly decidable.
